# add custom context menu to hosted web browser control

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, atl

I am hosting a web browser control, and want to provide my own context menu.

Ideally, I want to present my own context menu, that contains the original browser's context menu (with all addins etc.) as a sub menu.

If that's not possible / to tricky, I'd be ok with e.g. normally showing my context menu, and showing the original one when the user presses SHIFT.

Do I need to implement [IDocHostUIHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260(VS.85).aspx)? if yes, how do I specify a custom context menu, how can I force the original one? How do I get the control to use my implementation?

The control is created as such (error handling omitted):

```
HRESULT hr=AtlAxCreateControlEx(
   L"Shell.Explorer",m_wndWebCtrl.m_hWnd,
   NULL,NULL,(IUnknown**)&unk,
   IID_IWebBrowser2, NULL); // (IPersistStreamInit*)this);

hr = AtlAdviseSinkMap( this, true);

IUnknownPtr unk;
AtlAxGetControl(m_wndWebCtrl.m_hWnd, &unk);

IWebBrowser2Ptr browser2 = unk;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to implement `IDocHostUIHandler`.

Ok, i guess you could intercept right-clicks, keystrokes, and that other message that'll normally display a context menu... But that's probably gonna break badly sooner or later; at very least, i'd expect it to break accessibility.

Once you've intercepted [`IDocHostUIHandler::ShowContextMenu()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753264.aspx), you have the option of returning `S_OK` to squelch the built-in menu after showing your own. You can use the normal Win32 menu routines for this purpose, a custom control, or even fancy HTML if that's what does it for you. Per the documentation, enough context is provided to allow you to determine what element context is requested for, and what the default context menu *would* be.

Unfortunately, I know of no way to get a handle to the built-in menu. You could probably fake it by showing your context menu and then returning `S_FALSE` if the user chose the "original" option, but even then there's no way to attach the resulting menu to an existing popup menu (which really should be gone by the time you return anyway if you're running the modal-loop common to such popups). It is possible to [*add* options to the built-in menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313.aspx#Overiding_the_Contex).

You should be able to use [`GetKeyboardState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299.aspx) to determine the state of the shift key when the menu was requested.

---

Assuming you only want a subset of the normal browser functionality *anyway*, you might be better served by just re-implementing the options you want (back, forward, print) and invoking the appropriate command if the user chooses them. Alternately, if you only want normal menus in a very specific scenario (for instance: editing commands in a textarea), use the `ShowContextMenu()` arguments to identify this and only then return `S_FALSE` to trigger the default. I've had pretty good luck with this latter technique; after all, they *are* supposed to be **context** menus...

Comment: Thanks Shog :) I just don't want to cut off the user completely from the default functionality, So I guess GetKeyboardState will do the trick. Do also happen to know how I tell ATL to use my IDocHostUIHandler in its client site implementation?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, i'm afraid... Never tried it using ATL myself. Maybe this will help? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274202

Answer (score 1):

I am adding the following information how to "inject" your own DocHostUI implementation into the browser control:

The default way is to implement `IOleClientSite`, and support the `IDocHostUIHandler` on the implementing object.

There is a simpler way: In the `DocumentComplete` handler, query the `IHTMLDocumennt` for [`ICustomDoc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753272(VS.85).aspx), which allows you to supply your interface from a standalone object. This allows you to keep whatever IOleClientSite implementation your environment provides.

More details can be found [here](http://weborama.blogspot.com/2004/10/mshtml-hosting-idochostuihandler.html).